# How to consider other rows in a dataFrame when filtering?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I am trying to filter (and consequently change) certain rows in pandas that depend on values in other columns. Say my dataFrame looks like this:

```
SENT    ID    WORD        POS        HEAD
1       1     I           PRON        2
1       2     like        VERB        0
1       3     incredibly  ADV         4
1       4     brown       ADJ         5
1       5     sugar       NOUN        2
2       1     Here        ADV         2
2       2     appears     VERB        0
2       3     my          PRON        5
2       4     next        ADJ         5
2       5     sentence    NOUN        0
```

The structure is such that the 'HEAD' column points at the index of the word on which the row is dependent on. For example, if 'brown' depends on 'sugar' then the head of 'brown' is 4, because the index of 'sugar' is 4.

I need to extract a df of all the rows in which the POS is ADV whose head's POS VERB, so 'Here' will be in the new df but not 'incredibly',   (and potentially make changes to their WORD entry). 
At the moment I'm doing it with a loop, but I don't think it's the pandas way and it also creates problems further down the road. Here is my current code (the split("-") is from another story - ignore it):

```
def get_head(df, dependent):
    head = dependent
    target_index = int(dependent['HEAD'])
    if target_index == 0:
        return dependent
    else:
        if target_index < int(dependent['INDEX']):
            # 1st int in cell
                while (int(head['INDEX'].split("-")[0]) > target_index):
                    head = data.iloc[int(head.name) - 1]
        elif target_index > int(dependent['INDEX']):
            while int(head['INDEX'].split("-")[0]) < target_index:
                    head = data.iloc[int(head.name) + 1]
    return head
```

A difficulty I had when I wrote this function is that I didn't (at the time) have a column 'SENTENCE' so I had to manually find the nearest head. I hope that adding the SENTENCE column should make things somewhat easier, though it is important to note that as there are hundreds of such sentences in the df, simply searching for an index '5' won't do, since there are hundreds of rows where `df['INDEX']=='5'`.

Here is an example of how I use get_head():

```
def change_dependent(extract_col, extract_value, new_dependent_pos, head_pos):
    name = 0
    sub_df = df[df[extract_col] == extract_value] #this is another condition on the df. 
    for i, v in sub_df.iterrows():
        if (get_head(df, v)['POS'] == head_pos):
            df.at[v.name, 'POS'] = new_dependent_pos
    return df

change_dependent('POS', 'ADV', 'ADV:VERB', 'VERB')
```

Can anyone here think of a more elegant/efficient/pandas way in which I can get all the ADV instances whose head is VERB?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,'I','NOUN',2],
                  [1,2,'like','VERB',0],
                  [1,3,'incredibly','ADV',4],
                  [1,4,'brown','ADJ',4],
                  [1,5,'sugar','NOUN',5],
                  [2,1,'Here','ADV',2],
                  [2,2,'appears','VERB',0],
                  [2,3,'my','PRON',5],
                  [2,4,'next','ADJ',5],
                  [2,5,'sentance','NOUN',0]]
                  ,columns=['SENT','ID','WORD','POS','HEAD'])

adv=df[df['POS']=='ADV']
temp=df[df['POS']=='VERB'][['SENT','ID','POS']].merge(adv,left_on=['SENT','ID'],right_on=['SENT','HEAD']) 
temp['WORD']
```